# How pass parameters of controller's action to Ninject concrete type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have ProductController.cs

```
    namespace AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI.WebUI.Controllers
    {
        public class ProductController : Controller
        {

            public ProductController(IProductCollection productCollection)
            {
                _productCollection = productCollection;
            }

            public static string Title
            {
                get
                {
                    return _title;
                }
                set
                {
                    _title = value;
                }
            }
            public static int PageNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    return _pageNumber;
                }
                set
                {
                    _pageNumber = value;
                }
            }
            public static int ItemsPerPage
            {
                get
                {
                    return _itemsPerPage;
                }
                set
                {
                    _itemsPerPage = value;
                }
            }
            // GET: Product
            public ActionResult List(int page = 1, string search = null)
            {

                ProductListViewModel model = new ProductListViewModel
                {
                    Products = _productCollection.Products
                                                 .OrderBy(product => product.Title)
                                                 .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
                                                 .Take(pageSize),
                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                    {
                        CurrentPage = page,
                        ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
                        TotalItems = _productCollection.Products.Count()
                    }
                };
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
```

NinjectDependencyResolver.cs

```
namespace AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
            {
                // Create dependency here

                kernel.Bind<IProductCollection>().To<AmazonProductCollection>()
                                                 .WhenInjectedInto<ProductController>()
                                                 .WithConstructorArgument("title", ProductController.Title)
                                                 .WithConstructorArgument("pageNumber", ProductController.PageNumber)
                                                 .WithConstructorArgument("itemsPerPage", ProductController.ItemsPerPage);
            }
        }
    }
```

AmazonProductCollection class have constructor:

```
public AmazonProductCollection(string title, int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage)
```

I want that AmazonProductCollection get own parameters from action List parameters from Product controller, because some of this it gets when user fill TextBoxt and click to button "Search" in html-view form. For example I want use parameter string "search" from action List and transfer to AmazonProductCollection as constructor parameter "title".

I read this post: [How to pass parameters to a transient object created by Ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778567/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-transient-object-created-by-ninject), but I don't understand how possible to create same things in my situation.

Can somebody help me with Ninject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use a factory.

The factory interface would look something like this:

```
public interface IAmazonProductCollectionFactory
{
    AmazonProductCollection Create(string title, int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage);
}
```

Such interface would live in the same project where the controller is (the MVC project).

The implementation of such factory would look like this:

```
public class AmazonProductCollectionFactory : IAmazonProductCollectionFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot m_ResolutionRoot;

    public AmazonProductCollectionFactory (IResolutionRoot resolution_root)
    {
        m_ResolutionRoot = resolution_root;
    }

    public AmazonProductCollection Create(string title, int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage)
    {
        return resolution_root.Get<AmazonProductCollection>(
            new ConstructorArgument("title", title),
            new ConstructorArgument("pageNumber", pageNumber),
            new ConstructorArgument("itemsPerPage", pageNumber));
    }
}
```

The `AmazonProductCollectionFactory` would live inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) project. In your case, this is probably the same MVC project. Please note that having such factory that depends on `IResolutionRoot` any place except for the composition root is an example of service location which [is considered an anti-pattern](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html).

Now, instead of `IProductCollection`, you need to inject `IAmazonProductCollectionFactory` into the constructor of the `ProductController` and let the `List` action use it to create an `AmazonProductCollection` instance like this:

```
var productCollection = factory.Create(...);
```

where `factory` is the name of the instance variable that you used to store the injected `IAmazonProductCollectionFactory`.

Don't forget to register `IAmazonProductCollectionFactory` with the Ninject container.

Please note that you should consider creating a service that matches the requirements of the `List` action. For example, you can wrap the whole search logic inside a service that knows how to do the search and let such service worry about creating the `AmazonProductCollection` via the abstract factory. And then, instead of injecting the factory into the controller, you would inject the service into the controller.

Comment: Where better to put this factories classes? In domain project or mvc? Could you specify folder which better use for convension?

Comment: The factory should live in the composition root. This is as close as possible to the application entry point. The MVC project is a suitable place. Where are you having the `NinjectDependencyResolver` class? You can put the factory in the same folder of this class.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helps me!